# Как спрятать консоль при запуске скрипта Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Ниже мой код. Он во время выполнения открывает консоль. Вывода никакого в консоль нет, кроме первого запуска, поэтому я хочу, чтобы консоль открылась только при первом запуске кода, а при последующих нет. Как это сделать?

```
def file_to_array():
    result = []
    with open('input.txt') as f:
        for i in f.readlines():
            result.append(i.replace('\n', ''))
    return result


async def main():
    await client.send_message(chat, text)
    async for message in client.iter_messages(chat):
        if 0 < message.button_count < 11:
            await message.click(random.randint(0, message.button_count - 1))
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = file_to_string_array()

    chat = 'me'
    text = 'hi'

    client = TelegramClient(data[2], int(data[0]), data[1])
    with client:
        client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Если запускаете из windows двойным щелчком по файлу, просто поменяйте расширение на pyw, тогда файл будет запускаться с помощью pythonw.exe, который не открывает консоль при запуске.

Comment: @insolor а как сделать так, чтобы при первом запуске консоль открылась, а при последующих не открывалась?

Comment: @insolor и pyw не помогло, ничего не происходит при двойном нажатии

Comment: Я сейчас пробовал сделать через AllocConsole из win32console, консоль создается, но Python ее похоже не видит. Я бы попробовал сделать отдельный скрипт, который запускается в консоли (допустим, для каких-то настроек), и отдельный для работы в фоне без консоли.

Comment: "ничего не происходит при двойном нажатии" - а вы ничего и не должны увидеть. Проверьте через диспетчер задач, если pythonw в списке есть, значит все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Запускайте через pythonw

```
start pythonw mypythonprog
```

Либо используйте библиотеку win32gui

```
import win32gui, win32con;

frgrnd_wndw = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow();
wndw_title  = win32gui.GetWindowText(frgrnd_wndw);
if wndw_title.endswith("python.exe"):
    win32gui.ShowWindow(frgrnd_wndw, win32con.SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: Также можно просто удалять консоль с помощью `win32con.FreeConsole()`